# After authenticating, a redirection to the PWA UI is showing the service worker code instead

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, fetch-api

Accessing an installed PWA triggers an authentication page through SAML. After entering username and password the information is send through POST for verification:

```
Request URL: https://url/saml/SSO
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Upon success a 302 redirection to the PWA is performed:

```
Response Headers
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2019 09:58:49 GMT
Location: https://url/sw.js
```

However, when this is done the code of the service worker file is shown instead of the UI.

Included workaround for bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=573937:

```
let request = event.request;

  if (request.method == 'GET') {
    request = new Request(request.url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: request.headers,
      mode: request.mode == 'navigate' ? 'cors' : request.mode,
      credentials: request.credentials,
      redirect: request.redirect
    });
  }
```

The service worker configuration is as follows:

```
// Caches
var cacheStatic = 's1';
var cacheDynamic  = 'd1';

// Array with the files to cache
var cacheFiles = [
    '/',
    '/offline.html',
    '/index.html',
    '/images/icons/Android/mconnect-192x192.png',
    '/images/icons/Android/mconnect-512x512.png',
    '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    '/fonts/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css',
    '/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js',
    '/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
    '/js/app.js'
]

// Pre-cache static assets
self.addEventListener('install', function(event){
    self.skipWaiting();
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Installed');
    event.waitUntil(caches.open(cacheStatic).then(function(cache){
        console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching Application Shell Files');
        return cache.addAll(cacheFiles);
    }));
});

// Cleaning cache
self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
  console.log('Activating Service Worker ....', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
      .then(function (keyList) {
        return Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
          if (key !== cacheStatic && key !== cacheDynamic) {
            console.log('Removing old cache.', key);
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        }));
      })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

// Cache-Fetch Strategy
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

let request = event.request;

  if (request.method == 'GET') {
    request = new Request(request.url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: request.headers,
      mode: request.mode == 'navigate' ? 'cors' : request.mode,
      credentials: request.credentials,
      redirect: request.redirect
    });
  }

event.respondWith(
    // Try the network
    fetch(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        return caches.open(cacheDynamic)
          .then(function(cache) {
            // Put in cache if succeeds
            cache.put(event.request.url, response.clone());
            return response;
          })
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('[Error fetching]', err);
          // Fallback to cache if not offline
          return caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function(response){
                if (response === undefined) { 
                    // fallback to offline page
                    return caches.match('/offline.html');
                } 
                return response;
            })


      })
  );
});
```

The expected behavior is to see the UI of the application and not the code of the service worker file.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the same behaviour and had to make some files public (unprotected from SAML):
- ngsw.json
- ngsw-worker.js
- manifest.json

afterwards it worked as expected.